# HTML/CSS Responsive Laptop & Desktop

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a school project. I would like to make all the pages responsive for laptops & desktop.

I know that responsive is best use by % to determine width & height. For my case, I use pixels instead for some reasons.

Most of the pages have tables, and the tables have different height & width. I would only make css for desktop, and the current code (which is the width & height for the table) is for laptop.

What I want to do for desktop is to add both the table's height & width by 100px. e.g. Page A have height & width of 250px for laptop. If I use desktop, the height & width will be added up by 350px.

How can I do this?

Comment: Most likely media queries are what you are looking for. There's a great resource here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries
Using percentages from page-containers is a good idea for making elements responsive. You don't have to use them for heights - in fact, this gets dangerous, but using fluid widths and min-heights will take you pretty far!

Comment: Responsive for laptop and desktops?! i think you mean mobile no? Use hard coded values for your outermost elements (your main page wrapper). Everything else should use `%` or `em` -- trust me on this one. You should make it as flexible as possible, set the values for desktop and then override them for mobile when the screen is below a certain size.

Comment: @JavierBuzzi however, depending on your use case he stated that he must make it x, pxs. it is probably better to use fluid when possible rather than hard coded though. theres a lot of ideal ways to attack this particular problem

Comment: @Daemedeor: Fair enough. In my case thats the most common solution. (gave you a like :D )

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into @media queries (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), quick to learn you just specify the @media and then the condition and then normal css like below

```
@media (minWidth: 300px){
        #pageA {
          height: 300px;
          width: 300px;
        }
}
```

Comment: Yup! @ZulHazmi: ^ that

Comment: i did make media queries. But what I want to do is add +100px for height & width for all the pages correspondingly for desktop. Each pages have different height & width for laptop.

Comment: @ZulHazmi just do the math.